# android Gcm registrationID conflicts with 3rd party library like Parse

Tags: android, parsing

I have a simple project that use my gcm provider and also I want to implement parse library to send push for all user. But I have an issue about that situation. When I register the gcm with my GCMSenderID, I get the registrationID and then Parse register the gcm with its default GCMSenderID(1076345567071). Then I realized that the regID that get from my gcm provider has written the parse push table as deviceToken. For this reason I think, I cannot send push message to all devices with parse. 
I use parse quickstart implementation also make some research from parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android. 
How can I resolve this conflict?

Here is my implementation:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/icon" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="xxx.android" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="xxxx.android" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".gcm.ParseReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Application.java

```
    Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);
    Parse.initialize(this, ParseAPPLICATION_ID, ParseCLIENT_KEY);                    
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

Parse uses its default sender id to request a GCM registration token: In particular, the SDK will automatically register your app for push at startup time using Parse's sender ID (1076345567071) and will store the resulting registration ID in the deviceToken field of the app's current ParseInstallation. (from parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android). So at startup 2 registrations for GCM tokens are requested, and my question is: how can I be sure which regToken Parse receives vs which regToken my GCM implementation/client receives? In theory they could get mixed up?

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this issue with registering multiple senders by calling :

```
GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this).register(YOUR_GCMSENDERID,  PARSE_DEFAULT_GCM_SENDERID);
```

PARSE_DEFAULT_GCM_SENDERID = **1076345567071**

Comment: Many thanks for this answer the Parse Default senderID made all the difference .Cheers mate